# Event handler for a ContextMenuStrip of NotifyIcon in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, notifyicon, contextmenustrip

I want to write a click event for a `ContextMenuStrip`. I have linked
this context menu strip to a `NotifyIcon`.

How can I do that? This is the code I have used:

```
ContextMenuStrip checkers_contact_menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
checkers_contact_menu.Items.Add("Open Mailbox");
checkers_contact_menu.Items.Add("About");
alert_sender.ContextMenuStrip = checkers_contact_menu;
```

I tried this

```
ContextMenuStrip checkers_contact_menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
checkers_contact_menu.Items.Add("Open Mailbox",null,openMailBoxToolStripMenuItem_Click);

private void openMailBoxToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Mail box");
}
```

But I am getting an error saying that

> Error 1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemCollection.Add(string, System.Drawing.Image, System.EventHandler)' has some invalid arguments

PS: the code is working , I had the event handler as `ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e` which should have been `EventArgs e`. Now the code works fine. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stub out the event handler method:

```
private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   MessageBox.Show("About");
}
```

And then when you add your menu item, you specify the event handler method as one of its parameters:

```
checkers_contact_menu.Items.Add("About", null, aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click);
```

Comment: hi I tried the same but I get an error Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemCollection.Add(string, System.Drawing.Image, System.EventHandler)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @Niranjan You would have to show the code you are using.  Try editing your question to include that snippet.